# Chef - Read a file from git repo at runtime and use parse value in recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I would like to read a file from a checkout git repository to parse a config file and use this data to perform few resources commands.

```
git "/var/repository" do
    action :sync
end

config = JSON.parse(File.read("/var/repository/config.json" ))
config.each do |job, flags|
    #do some resources stuff here
end
```

This will not work because the file doesn't exist at compile time:

> ================================================================================
>    Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/...
>    ================================================================================
>
> Errno::ENOENT
>
> ---
>
> No such file or directory - /var/repository/config.json

I where trying to load the file in ruby_block and perform the Chef resource actions there, but this didn't worked. Also setting the parsed config to a variable and use it outside of the ruby_block didn't work.

```
ruby_block "load config" do
    block do
        config = JSON.parse(File.read("/var/repository/config.json"))
        #node["config"] = config doesn't work - node["config"] will not be set

        config.each do |job, flags|
            #do some stuff - will not work because Chef context is missing
        end
    end
end
```

Any idea how I could read the file at runtime and used the parsed values in my recipe?

Comment: You should run your git resource at compile time for this specific case. Replace the `end` by `end.run_action(:sync)` and it should be ok.

Comment: Worked well!
Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Ok, worked well until you setup a new node without git.
The git_resouce isn't taking care of the git command.
Means I have to take care of the git installation & all ssh-keys before the git will perform.
source: https://docs.getchef.com/resource_git.html

Comment: Nope you have to install the package (again at compile time for your case)

Answer (score 0):

You may also find it helpful to use [lazy evaluation](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation) in scenarios like this.

> In some cases, the value for an attribute cannot be known until the execution phase of a chef-client run. In this situation, using lazy evaluation of attribute values can be helpful. Instead of an attribute being assigned a value, it may instead be assigned a code block.

Comment: ? This would involves (for OP case where a bunch of resource are defined from the file content) to encapsulate all in a ruby_block and then awfully play with the resource run_context. which means no view in handlers or anything else :/